# extended ASCII characters not working in int 10h

Tags: c, x86, nasm, bootloader, bios

I have a simple OS (real mode), written in NASM (only bootloader) and most in C.

I want to print this character: ñ, and I use this function that uses int 10h to print a character to screen:

```
void putch(char chr)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x10"
                          :
                          : "a" ((0x0e<<8) | chr),
                            "b" (0x0000));
}

void println(char *str)
{
    while (*str)
        putch(*str++);
}
```

Now, I attempt to print ñ:

```
println("ñ\r\n");
```

But when I compile and execute (in qemu and VB box), the character "ñ" is ignored.
I saved source code in CP-437 encoding, but the problem stills.
This affects also all the extended ASCII characters.

Comment: @usr2564301 I've edited - it is clear that int 10h,0Eh is meant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is simple. In x86 compilers `char` is **signed**. `'ñ'`, i.e. `0xA4` is considered negative (-92). A signed `char` be promoted to `int` (usual arithmetic promotions) for `|`. This happens through sign-extension.

The resulting value will be of course -92 (`0xFFA4`), which `|`ed with `0x0E00` will result in `0xFFA4`... which will mean that instead of function AH=0Eh we're now calling the function AH=FFh... if it even exists.

One solution is to have `putch` take an argument as **`int`** and convert it to **`unsigned char`**, just like the C functions `putchar` & al do:

```
void putch(int chr)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("int $0x10"
                          :
                          : "a" ((0x0e<<8) | (unsigned char)chr),
                            "b" (0x0000));
}
```

Or just make it accept the argument as an `unsigned char` like suggested in the comments.

Comment: Details: 1) "In x86 char is signed." --> It is not the processor, but the compiler that makes `char` signed.  2) "ñ will be promoted to a negative int" is like the effective results, but it was the coding of `"ñ"` to a `char` that made `str[0]` negative - no `int` involved yet.  The promotion from `char` to `int` in `(0x0e<<8) | chr` did not change the value.  3) Using `putch(int chr)` instead of `putch(char chr)` is a good idea, yet `putch(char chr)` would have had the same outcome.

Comment: @chux : In the original `((0x0e<<8) | chr)` wouldn't have `chr` been promoted to a signed integer. If it was negative it would have had the sign extended through the entire `int` and had 0x0e00 ore'ed to it? That should have produced the effect Anti was referring to where the bits 8-15 were set to 1 with the promotion so oring anything with them still kept bits 8-15 set. In the end you get the value 0xFF??

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes the effect is like as you comment, yet the explanation of the steps sounded to me like the promotion made  the value negative when the value passed was negative already.

Comment: I would have defined it as `void putch(unsigned char)` to specify that we want zero-extension, and let callers know that we ignore the upper byte(s) of the input in case it's not inlined.  Or with clang, the compiler requires the register arg to be zero-extended, and uses a copy-and-add with LEA to set the upper byte (instead of zeroing the upper bytes itself when the arg is an int and we cast it to a narrow type).  GCC strangely uses `or ah, 14`, instead of the shorter `mov ah, 14`. https://godbolt.org/z/n1xDB7.  I think both result in AH being renamed separately on P6/SnB...

Comment: @PeterCordes : passing around chars as integers for console input and output (and file streams)  is an old tradition going back to K&R. Since `getchar` returns EOF as a negative value outside the 8 bit range it seems they standardized on int being passed around for all the related functions. The _C_ library still does it today.